How to get siddhi in Rama mantra?
What is Japa Vidhana of Rama mantra to get siddhi for shudras ?
How shudras should do anganyasa and karanyasa without  Swaha, Vashat, Vaushat .. etc ?
“According to dharma Sidhu and brihaddharma purāṇa , Shudras should not recite Swaha, Vashat, Vaushat .. etc.”
How shudras should do havan without swahakara ?
“स्त्रीशूद्राभ्यां न होतव्यं मन्त्रोच्चारणपूर्वकम्। (पुरश्चर्यार्णव पृ. 549)
होमस्तु ब्राह्मणद्वारा स्त्रीशूद्राणां निगद्यते । (पुरश्चर्यार्णव पृ. 550)
शूद्राणामधिकारोऽस्मिँस्तान्त्रिके होमकर्मणि ।
व‌ह्निजायां परित्यज्य स्वाहान्ते च नमो मतः ।। (पुरश्चर्यार्णव पृ. 550)”
What is tantrika text related to Rama sadhakas ?
